# Importing GoogleWebRTC pod fails: module 'GoogleWebRTC' not found

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am currently working on a Kotlin multiplatform and am trying to interface with the GoogleWebRTC pod.

The pod exists, I was able to import it in a separate project (without Kotlin multiplatform). I can see the `.framework` is created in my build directory, however when doing a gradle sync or building from Xcode, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: /var/folders/hv/9cx28nxx4gz9hj_m86bp5rx40000gn/T/tmp362966650322311128.m:1:9: fatal error: module 'GoogleWebRTC' not found
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.UtilsKt.ensureNoCompileErrors(Utils.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesASTFiles(ModuleSupport.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesInfo(ModuleSupport.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.buildNativeLibrary(main.kt:499)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.processCLib(main.kt:264)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.interop(main.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.InteropCompilerKt.invokeInterop(InteropCompiler.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:37)

Execution failed for task ':shared:cinteropGoogleWebRTCIosArm64'.
> Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

AFNetworking seems to work fine, but adding the WebRTC pod seems to break the project.

Am I missing a limitation of Kotlin multiplatform or something?

This is my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
    cocoapods {
        // Configure fields required by CocoaPods.
        summary = "Some description for a Kotlin/Native module"
        homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"

        // You can change the name of the produced framework.
        // By default, it is the name of the Gradle project.
        frameworkName = "shared"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "10.0"

        pod("GoogleWebRTC", "~> 1.1")
        pod("AFNetworking", "~> 4.0.0")
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue but I didn't figure out the reason why.

It seems a there's something wrong with GoogleWebRTC pod and the Kotlin-native/cocoapods integration.

I've opened an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43512).

We have an official help.

It seems that the frameworks name is different from the pod name. So a possible solution could be that:

```
kotlin {
    cocoapods {
        [...]
        pod("GoogleWebRTC", moduleName = "WebRTC", version = "~> 1.1")
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

I tried it and it works.

Comment: This worked great, however am getting this error now:

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: @RémiVansteelandt hard to say. Probably a project misconfiguration. You should provide more info about your projects `shared` and `iOS` but I think that should be a different question topic.

Comment: Man, you're a lifesaver! I had been stuck with this problem for a week! I had tried literally everything and finally came across your answer it solved my issue. Thank you!